# Powershell to download files with certain name

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, binaryfiles

Hello and thank you in advance. Currently I have a script running that downloads files from one location to another. I'm trying to clean up the script to only download files that have `_Lthumb` in the file name. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following line in which I added is causing the problems. Wheni remove it, the script runs fine, but it doesn't filter the data by `_Lthumb`:

```
| Where-Object {$_.Name -Match '*_Lthumb'}
```

Here is the script, including the portion above that breaks it:

```
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}
######################## Start Variables ########################
$destination = "\\pulse-dev.hinshawad.com\C$\ProfilePhotos\ProfilePictures"
$webUrl = "http://mysites.hinshawad.com"
$listUrl = "http://mysites.hinshawad.com/user photos/profile pictures/"
##############################################################
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl
$list = $web.GetList($listUrl)
function ProcessFolder {
param($folderUrl)
$folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
foreach ($file in $folder.Files | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match '*_Lthumb'} ) {
#Ensure destination directory
$destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
{
$dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 
}
#Download file
$binary = $file.OpenBinary()
    #$stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" +     $file.Name), Create
$stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" +     ($file.Name -replace "_Lthumb")), Create
$writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
$writer.write($binary)
$writer.Close()
}
}
#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download files in folders
#foreach ($folder in $list.Folders)   {

#ProcessFolder($folder.URL)
#}
```

Comment: Try `-like`, Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*_Lthumb'}

Comment: The `-match` operator is regular expression based. The asterisk `*` is a RegEx quantifier meaning any number of previous, but there is nothing before it. So it's not clear what you intend. If you want to filter for `_Lthumb` at the end of the Name, do as @KoryGill suggests or use `| Where-Object {$_.Name -Match '_Lthumb$'}` (the `$` anchors at the end)

Comment: Thank you, these both work great, thanks!